# Why does Android Studio installer place the Android SDK into the %USER% folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, path, sdk

Android Studio installer places AS into `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio` where it is globally available.
However, it places the Android SDK into `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` which is technically private to that user and not available to other users who might execute the globally available Android Studio. Why is the SDK installed into a "User Folder"?

Note:
I know you can override this and put the SDK at any location you wish. I just want to understand the design choice that puts the SDK at a user private location by default.

Note 2:
I have put in a different folder location for the SDK in the Android Studio installer and in fact the SDK was installed there.
However, the SDK Manager/Gradle did not seem to know this and subsequent updates of the SDK by Gradle put the SDK into the "User Folder".
So I ended up with two SDKs installed.

Comment: "I just want to understand the design choice" -- questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not well-suited for Stack Overflow. Only Developer X can answer definitively, and Developer X is unlikely to see the question. Everyone else is likely to only be able to offer opinions.

Comment: Commonsware, i like your book. I even paid some money. Please, cool down.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of programs install this way. It makes sense as default, so there is only one install of program, but users' files are private and safe. It would be wrong for files to be available to other users as a default. It should be a choice to share files not a default. There are also version control issues with sharing files without source control of some type.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I'm not sure what problems there would be sharing the ADK. In any case, the Studio installer asks where you want the ADK located and it will put the ADK in a shared location if you ask. However this information is not passed to the SDK manager and later when the manager runs (if you don't overide) it puts another copy of the ADK at the private user location. This would see to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

SDK is installed in user folder because then SDK Manager (when launched under your account) will have the necessary permissions to update Android SDK.